# redis исключения

Tags: php, redis

Как вызвать исключение, если память (swap и озу) закончатся? Смог сделать такую ситуацию. Вызвалось исключение
`error: Uncaught RedisException: LOADING Redis is loading the dataset in memory`

Как избежать таких ситуаций ?

Comment: можно например установить редису максимальный размер памяти `$redis->config('set', 'maxmemory', $memoryLimitBytes);` потом каждую запись обернуть в `try catch` и ловить `RedisException`

Comment: но учитывай, что  Redis может автоматически удалить старые ключи, чтобы освободить место

Comment: А как сделать без явного указания памяти

Comment: Если без то с костылями. каждые n - записей проверяй использование памяти редисом `$redis->info('memory')` далее достань к-ство использованой памёяти системы, к примеру что то типа `exec("grep MemTotal /proc/meminfo", $aryMem)`  потом считай сколько потенциальной памяти у него осталось, к примеру если меньше 100-200мб то выбрасывай собственное исключение. Но это плохой вариант. как по мне лучше на крон повесить скрипт который будет работать раз в пару сек и чекать память. к примеру если ее мало то ставь какой нить флаг в редисе что записывать нельзя, а в php при инициализации чекай этот флаг

Comment: А 100-200 мб какой памяти ? он может же память из свапа брать. Так невозможно узнать реальный остаток памяти

Comment: Да но своп работает чуть иначе, он как раз сделан для освобождения оперативки. Т е если в свопе есть место но ОЗУ не хватает - он перенесет что то в своп. Соответственно у тебя не будет такого варианта где ОЗУ заполнено а своп нет. Сори за Т9 :D